# SQL: Matching whole string unsorted

Tags: sql, string, stored-procedures, cursor

I've got a parameter (@FULL_NAME) filled with an unsorted full name, using the comma as a separator for every word. I want to select all the rows of a table which include all the words from this parameter.

Here's an example, the person i'm looking for is:

- First name: "JUAN MARTIN"
- Last name: "LOPEZ"

The parameter @FULL_NAME has the vale: 'MARTIN,LOPEZ,JUAN'

Here's the code I'm using to find the row:

```
DECLARE
    @SQL nvarchar(max),
    @FULL_NAME nvarchar(max),
    @AUX nvarchar(max)

SET @FULL_NAME = 'MARTIN,LOPEZ,JUAN'
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE '

DECLARE AUX CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR (SELECT strval FROM dbo.Split(@FULL_NAME,','))
OPEN AUX

FETCH NEXT FROM AUX INTO @AUX
SET @SQL = @SQL + ''' '' + First_Name + '' '' + Last_Name + '' '' LIKE ''% ' + @AUX + ' %'''

FETCH NEXT FROM AUX INTO @AUX
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND '' '' + First_Name + '' '' + Last_Name + '' '' LIKE ''% ' + @AUX + ' %'''
    FETCH NEXT FROM AUX INTO @AUX
END 

CLOSE AUX
DEALLOCATE AUX

SELECT @SQL
```

Is there any way of doing this simpler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Join the `People` table with the Table values Function  `dbo.Split` on `Like` condition. Something like this.

```
SELECT First_Name
FROM   PEOPLE A
       JOIN dbo.Split(@FULL_NAME, ',') B
         ON A.First_Name + ' ' + A.Last_Name LIKE '%' + B.strval + '%'
GROUP  BY first_name
HAVING Count (*) = (SELECT Count(*)
                    FROM   dbo.Split(@FULL_NAME, ','))
```

Comment: That won't work as needed. With that code you would get all the rows which include at least one word of the parameter @FULL_NAME . I need to get the ones which include all of it.

Comment: @smopuiM - Updated try now.

Comment: Thank you! This code actually works. I didn't know about the "having" condition. Now I'm wondering which code should I use, the original is a bit faster, but this one is pretty simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE 
WHERE First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name 
                        LIKE  '%' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(@FULL_NAME, ',','.') , 1) + '%'
 OR   First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name 
                        LIKE  '%' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(@FULL_NAME, ',','.') , 2) + '%'
 OR   First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name 
                        LIKE  '%' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(@FULL_NAME, ',','.') , 3) + '%'
```

Comment: The amount of words in the parameter @FULL_NAME is not fixed.